# Disable Doxygen warnings for a specific folder

Tags: doxygen

Is there a way to disable Doxygen warnings for a specific folder?

Just to be clear, I still want the documentation for the files inside it to be generated, I just don't care about the warnings.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No there are no possibilities for this, it is all or nothing.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your comment. I'll use grep to filter the warnings. Go ahead and post your comment as an answer.